# Google Plus Font Awesome Icon won't display - the rest icons work fine

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I want to make a `Contact` section for a webpage, using font awesome icons for the various social media. I have succesfully used the rest icons (`Facebook`, `Twitter`, `Linkedin`, even an envelope icon which prompts emailing), and I've also used font awesome icons for a little coffee mug on the footer of my page. 
The only FA icon that can't be displayed is the `Google+` icon. The code I have used is the same for each case, changing respectively the name of the icons:

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
```

I have checked my brackets and even moved the icon around the page, wherever it goes it can't be displayed. Is this an issue that has to do with the version of my browser? How can I make my icon visible? Thank you.

Edit: The [icon's page](https://fontawesome.com/icons/google-plus-g?style=brands) and a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/IoannaZapalidi/pen/WzgoLM)

Comment: try removing -g
<i class="fa fa-google-plus">

Comment: Apparently it has to do with the version of Font Awesome each person uses, which I neglected to notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> fa-google-plus

is font-awesome v4

> fa-google-plus-g

is font-awesome v5

From the link in the original post

> This icon replaces Font Awesome 4's fa-google-plus
>   We created a shim to help folks upgrade easily their existing projects from Font Awesome 4 to 5 and avoid those embarrassing missing icon moments.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="#"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
```

You were missing the `b` on `fab`

Comment: I did try this, but instead of fixing the issue, it kept on displaying nothing (the browser inspector says the icon is 57.1 X 1 pixels on my screen), it altered the CSS since the class of the element changed... :/
Edit: I changed the height of the element to 20px (matching the rest icons) and it's still not visible, but the CSS is the same as the rest once more.

Comment: We can assume that the problem isn't on this line then. As i've tested it on my page and it's working as intended. 

Which other css properties are being applied to the icon? Be it from another classes, or from parents.

Answer (score 1):

Removing -g worked for me.

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p4nykvzb/

Comment: Apparently it has to do with the version of Font Awesome each person uses, which I neglected to notice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fa fa-google-plus-circle` or `fa fa-google-plus-square`. It will work!